# Why a background process forces the parent to exit when background process exits with status 1?

Tags: linux, bash

My Bash code :

```
#!/bin/sh
set -ex
function func ()
{
    sleep $1
        echo $1
if [ $1 -eq 10 ]; then
 exit 1
fi
}

func 10 &
pid_a=$!
func 5 &
pid_b=$!
func 3 &
pid_c=$!
wait $pid_b
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo "b.ksh SUCCESS"; else echo "b.ksh FAILED"; fi
wait $pid_c
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then echo "c.ksh SUCCESS"; else echo "c.ksh FAILED"; fi
wait $pid_a
if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
echo "a.ksh SUCCESS"; else echo "a.ksh FAILED"; fi
```

When it is run with `set -ex` enabled:

```
sh-4.2$ ./ex.sh 
+ pid_a=16341
+ func 10
+ pid_b=16342
+ sleep 10
+ func 5
+ pid_c=16343
+ sleep 5
+ wait 16341
+ func 3
+ sleep 3
+ echo 3
3
+ '[' 3 -eq 10 ']'
+ echo 5
5
+ '[' 5 -eq 10 ']'
+ echo 10
10
+ '[' 10 -eq 10 ']'
+ exit 1
```

Here parent also exited along with background process that exited with status 1.
Can you explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do

```
command
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then ...
```

in a `set -e`-using script. The script will end because of the nonzero exit status of command before it even gets to the `if`.

And `wait` reports the exit status of the waited-on process as its own exit status (orherwise the `$?` check would be pointless anyway). Try this instead:

```
if wait $pid_x; then
 echo "x.ksh SUCCESS"
else
 echo "x.ksh FAILED"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

The manual for bash says of [`set -e`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Set-Builtin):

> `-e`   Exit immediately if a simple command (see SHELL GRAMMAR above) exits with a non-zero status.  The
>                         shell does not exit if the command that fails is part of the command list immediately following a
>                         `while`  or `until` keyword, part of the test in an `if` statement, part of a `&&` or `||` list, or if the
>                         command's return value is being inverted via `!`.  A trap on ERR, if set, is  executed  before  the
>                         shell exits.

It doesn't say anything about 'when a background process exits with a non-zero status, the shell will not terminate' — so it did terminate when the background process failed.

Comment: The shell *doesn't* terminate when the child process exits. It terminates when the `wait` command waiting on the child exits.